# How to find class _XWk with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, element, findall

I've found out how to locate Google's "quick answer box" by searching for the "_XWk HTML Element by using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests

URL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=when%20was%20trump%20born'
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all("div", {"class": "_XWk"}))
```

But, after numerous failed attempts, Line 10 repeatedly returns

> [ ]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First at all take a look into your `soup` - There is the truth.

The `classes` are generated dynamically, so it is not the best idea to use them for a selection - Try to focus on `id`, `element` or "more fix" `attributes`.

In my case there is no such a `class` "_XWk".

Alternativ approach to select the box and respective the date of birth:

```
soup.select_one('#rcnt > div:nth-of-type(2) [data-attrid="kc:/people/person:born"]').text
```